# The beta feature EseDiskFlushConsistency is enabled in ESENT due to the beta site mode settings 0x800000

Tags: windows, logging, filesystems

I see the following messages in Windows Application log:

> svchost (3612,G,0) The beta feature EseDiskFlushConsistency is enabled
>   in ESENT due to the beta site mode settings 0x800000.

What does it mean?

Comment: Not sure what this is but there's an ongoing discussion about this here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/78abzl/beta_feature_in_windows_update/ When I get this error, my system freezes for like 3 seconds, every time. This event occurs every hour at least once. It seems to have something to do with extensible storage engine
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Storage_Engine I have searched for solutions but couldn't find anything until now. This problem drives me mad.

Comment: I think this question should be on Super User site - stackoverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: To date, I haven't noticed any ill effects from it. Nevertheless, it startled me to see that it comprised a significant percentage of the messages in an extract of Application Event Log records generated over the past 24 hours. The only thing I have observed that might be related is a couple of brief lags in file writes, such as when I save a file of notes that has grown to a few megabytes. The machine in question is brand new, running Windows 10 Fall Creators Update off a 512 GB solid state boot drive, with a second 2 TB 7200 RPM magnetic drive running on a separate SATA channel.

Comment: I'm getting this too - causes the icons on my taskbar to refresh or the mouse pointer to show a circular progress bar ("busy pointer"). On reddit someone posted that uninstalling Adobe Acrobat Reader fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

**ESENT** is the Extensiible Storage Engine runtime - part of an single-file transactional database similar to SQLite. ESE is used in several Microsoft services and applications to store data - for example, Edge might use it to store the history of pages you've visited.

The message suggests that some kind of different/new method is being used to ensure consistency of data during flushing (moving of data from one area to another - for a database. typically from RAM to disk). Apparently they forgot to remove this message before putting this method into the release channel.

I have searched for solutions but couldnt find anything till now.But I wouldn't worry too much about it. Because it doesn't crash, does it?